# What versions of Windows are currently the most popular

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-xp

Does anyone have a ballpark percentage breakdown of Windows versions currently being used out there?

For example, 60% are using Vista, 30% XP etc etc.

We are currently building an installer and we need to know what will give us the most coverage.  What we are particularly interested in is the prevalance of .NET versions as our application has a dependency on .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: Please explain how this is programming-related.

Comment: Duncan: It *could* have been programming-related. If you'd related this question to a programming need somehow ("Do i need to keep supporting Windows ME?").

Comment: Voting to reopen, since my question was answered.

Comment: Cheers, sorry I should have been more verbose in my original post.  Also, the answers indicate that the 60MB bootstrap .NET install issue will probably be haunting us until Windows 7 starts to get some grip.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look at [w3schools browser stats](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_os.asp).

Edit:

Since a lot of people seemed interested in this, I plotted the stats as a graph:

[alt text http://lanfear.c0la.se/~emil/osmarketshare.jpg](http://lanfear.c0la.se/~emil/osmarketshare.jpg)

Comment: Interesting... the adoption of Vista is even slower than I thought

Comment: Indeed. I might add that w3schools is ranked as one of the top thousand most visited sites on the net according to alexa, so their logs a probably based on enough data to be rather accurate. However, since it's a web development site, there's probably some bias since web developers are probably more likely to use some platforms such as firefox and linux/mac than the average user.

Comment: Vista comment by Andomar is my exact reaction

Comment: I would argue that w3schools is a lousy site to pull this information from for the simple reason that only technical users visit it.

Comment: Yep. That's a valid concern. I do however believe that this reflects more on the browser stats than on the OS stats. Granted, w3schools will probably show a higher percentage of linux users, and a higher percentage of firefox users. I don't think that the distribution of windows versions differs that much from normal users, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some stats for my site

```
XP                  71.81%
Vista               21.67%
Server 2003         5.28%    
NT                  0.97%
2000                0.28%
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exact numbers, but I am pretty sure XP is the most used one.

This wikipedia articles gives some numbers and claims Windows XP to be 63.53% market share.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Windows_versions

Comment: Here's a better Wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_desktop_operating_systems

Answer (score 1):

XP is **definitely** the most used, since Vista came out with several problems people don't like, but soon Windows 7 will be out which is a refined version of Vista. So that could make a dramatic change.

[Windows market share](http://www.computerworld.com/action/article.do?command=viewArticleBasic&articleId=9121938) goes in detail of some numbers you can look at.

Answer (score 1):

Valve releases their survey statistics.  Helps with operating system versions, but not your .NET 3.5 issue.

http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey

Answer (score 0):

My own experience , I have changed 3 job in 2 years working for 1000+ people company. They all use XP. 
Never heard anything about upgrading to Vista plan.